# The electric current going through a person in case of failure

Tags: electricity, electric-current

[image: Situational picture]

So the picture is basically what's going on. The person has the resistance of 2476 ohms and the conductor has real resistance at 1.22 ohms/km.

I figured I could solve it easily with $\frac{U}{R_{human}+0.1km 1.22 ohms/km}$
but the answer is not correct from this.

Comment: In case of the isolator failure, the current might go through the person. Then the current will take the path from the source (top left) and incur a resistance of 0.122 Ohm, as you have calculated. Then it will go through the human into the ground, incurring a resistance of 2476 Ohm. From there, it will go through the ground to the place where the power plant is grounded (bottom left). In that case, you have to add the resistors (serial circuit) and you get your results with $I = U / R$. Since that apparently is the wrong answer, there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

So:

$R_{total}=$ $R_{conductor} +$$R_{parallelconductor}$$=R_{conductor}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_{human}}+\frac{1}{R_{conductor}}}$ and calculated the total current at $I=U/R$ 
And then I calculated the $I_{human}$ with $I_{human} = I\frac{R2}{R1+R2}~=46.45 mAmp$